# Have a var return a specific value based on an if statement

Tags: javascript, for-loop, if-statement

I have written a for loop to sing 99 Bottles of Beer on the Wall. I am using an if statement to return a specific value to **var word**. When the number of bottles is 99 to 2 then **var word="bottles"** and when the number of bottles is 1 then **var word = "bottle"**. This works fine but in the final line of the final iteration when the number of bottles is 0 and I expect **var word** to equal "bottles", it is still coming up as "bottle".

```
var word="bottles";
for (var count = 99; count > 0; count-- ) { 
   document.write(count + " " + word + " of beer on the wall, <br>");
    document.write(count + " " + word + " of beer.<br>" );
    document.write("Take one down, pass it around,<br>");
    var count2 = count - 1;
        if (count2 === 1) {
        word = "bottle";
        }
    document.write(count2 + " " + word + " of beer on the wall.<br><br>");
    }
```

Is the condition of my if statement incorrect? This is what the final three iterations look like in the browser:

3 bottles of beer on the wall,
3 bottles of beer.
Take one down, pass it around,
2 bottles of beer on the wall.

2 bottles of beer on the wall, 
2 bottles of beer.
Take one down, pass it around,
1 bottle of beer on the wall.

1 bottle of beer on the wall, 
1 bottle of beer.
Take one down, pass it around,
0 bottle of beer on the wall.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You missed an `else` part to reset to `bottles`, please give a try with this script

```js
var word="bottles";
for (var count = 99; count > 0; count-- ) { 
   document.write(count + " " + word + " of beer on the wall, <br>");
    document.write(count + " " + word + " of beer.<br>" );
    document.write("Take one down, pass it around,<br>");
    var count2 = count - 1;
        if (count2 === 1) {
        word = "bottle";
        } else
 { word = "bottles";
 }
    document.write(count2 + " " + word + " of beer on the wall.<br><br>");
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

If the `count` is `1` then you change the word to `"bottle"`.

You have no code that changes it back.

The code on line 1 isn't run again: It is outside the loop.

So the last time you go around the loop, the `if` statement isn't entered, but the value has already been changed to `"bottle"`.

You need to set it to `"bottles"` inside the loop.